# How much stardust do I need to trade my Charcadet in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

This is my Charcadet. I tried to trade it with my other account but it said I don't have enough stardust

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on if the other account has Charcadet registered in its dex, as well as your friendship level.

If Charcadet is registered in the recipient's Pokédex, it only costs 100 stardust to trade at any friendship level. Otherwise it costs 20,000 stardust at Good Friends, 16,000 stardust at Great Friends, 1,600 stardust at Ultra Friends, and 800 stardust at Best Friends.